# php preg_replace replace array name from input

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, domdocument

hello as described from the title :
I have an input like this 
 `<input type="hidden" name="test[]" />`
 what I want to do is to remove [] from the name attribute so it will look like this
 `<input type="hidden" name="test" />`
I want to use it using regex or domdocument. thanks for the help.

ps : I have many input so they will be random name attribute not only test.
I'm using foreach() code to get all posts from a website so inputs with arrays in name attribute doesn't get submited that's why .

Comment: why not just type it directly, as in `<input type="hidden" name="test">`? Any particular reason you want to use regex for the task?

Comment: jQuery `$('[name="test[]"]').attr('name',  'test')`

Comment: if you do this, then you'll have to adjust your submission processing code, as those fields will become simple strings, not arrays.

Comment: To be able to write a DOMDocument-based solution, you should let us know what to look for. Any `input` that has a `name` attribute whose value ends with `[]`?

Comment: I'm using foreach() code to get all posts

Comment: it works fine but in some inputs that has arrays in names I can't get value of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you are after:

```
$html = "<<YOUR_HTML_STRING>>"
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
// Or use $dom->loadHTMLFile($url)

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$inputs = $xpath->query('//input[@name]'); // Get all <input> tags with name attributes

foreach($inputs as $input) { 
    $name = $input->getAttribute('name'); // Get the name attribute value
    if (substr($name, -2) === "[]") {     // If it ends with [], replace
        $newval = substr($name, 0, $input->getAttribute('name')->length - 2);
        $input->setAttribute('name', $newval);  // Set the new value
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8891NE)